# Android samsung disable remote recording

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-audiorecord, opensl

I am doing audio recording on Android.
I see that in Android-7 on Samsung it doesn't record the remote party.
I read that some manufacturers have blocked it.
But some apps (like ACR and Boldbeast Audio recorder) overcome this problem.
Any clue will be appreciated.